# Collapsing Header and Array of Flag

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

My friend makes a program where users can collapse headers of tableview.

So he need to keep track which headers are being collapsed and what's not.

He currently does that with a simple array of integer. I got this thing with using C array directly.

How do you keep track which headers collapse or not?

Comment: What have you tried?  Post your code.  What does "I got this thing with using C array directly" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Just use Xib on the delegate for table headers and detect clicks there. Problem solved.

Load XIB in
 (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section